# informatica powercenter - write $ sign into parameter file using command task

Tags: parameter-passing, informatica-powercenter

Are there any ways to write the `$` sign in a parameter file using a command task?

I have tried to use something like
`printf "\x24\x24PARAM_NAME=PARAM_VAL\n" >> parfile.parm`
however this gives me the problem of having to escape the quotes and slashbacks, and the task fails no matter what I try.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `echo \$\$PARAM_NAME=PARAM_VAL >> parfile.parm`

Comment: amazing... it does work! I must have confused myself at some stage with quotes and then it got more and more complex...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

edit - see answer above for much more simple solution!
After a lot of trial and error, it turned out that replacing the double quotes by single quotes worked.
I found out that Informatica uses sh -c "the_command" including these quotes, which seems to break up any and all attempts to use " inside the text no matter how many escape characters etc before it. It just did not work and this confirms other people's responses.